# How to rewrite a nested loop using the C++ STL algorithms?

Tags: c++, algorithm, for-loop, vector, stl

The loop is simple enough, but I just can't seem to wrap my head around using the STL algorithms to give the same nested loop below.

```
const int a_size = 5; // input
const int c_size = 2; // output
const int b_size = a_size * c_size; // multipliers

std::vector<float> a(a_size);
std::vector<float> b(b_size);
std::vector<float> c(c_size);

// fill a and b with data

// this nested loop
for(int i = 0; i<c_size; i++) {
    c[i] = 0.0;
    for(int k = 0; k<a_size; k++) {
        c[i] += (a[k] * b[i*a_size+k]);
    }
    c[i] = sigmoid(c[i]);
}
```

The reason why I would like to do this, is for the Boost.Compute library, which would do the calculations on the GPU using STL-like algorithms (std::transform, std::for_each, etc.).

Comment: It seems that one can rewrite your algorithm using matrix operations.

Comment: I think it is better to allow users to write arbitrary kernels in `Boost.Compute` - it will be much more useful. For instance via [`TaskGraph`](http://ideone.com/qQ4Pvo) method which I described [here](http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/compute-GPGPU-Library-Request-For-Feedback-tp4643691p4643927.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I came up [with](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/258c0a8ee9ddacb9):

```
auto i = 0;
generate(begin(c), end(c), [&i, &a, &b]
{
    return sigmoid(inner_product
    (
        begin(a), end(a),
        begin(b) + distance(begin(a), end(a)) * i++, 0.f
    ));
});
```

But it does not look pretty well - probably in such case I would prefer to write my own algorithm.

Or use matrix-form. With [`Eigen`](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) library it will became:

```
MatrixXd b;
VectorXd a, c;
// ...
c = (b*a).unaryExpr(sigmoid);
```

Comment: It will take me a while to digest that. Never heard of Eigen, does it support computations on the GPU?

Comment: @user1973386 AFAIK - for the moment it does not support GPU. Though it does vectorization via intrinsics (SSE2, etc). I have just found following thing: [`gpumatrix`](https://github.com/rudaoshi/gpumatrix) - "*A matrix and array library on GPU with interface compatible with Eigen*" - I think it worth to look too.

Comment: Too bad it does not support OpenCL just yet, but it's planned. I'll keep track of that library :).

Comment: @nijansen As I understand from [code-sample](http://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.4/code.html) - It just provides types similar to GLSL for C++, but not does computations on GPU.

Answer (score 8):

in fact the nested loop is algorithm std::inner_product.

```
auto first = std::begin( b );
auto increment = std::distance( std::begin( a ), std::end( a ) );
//,,

c[i] = std::inner_product( std::begin( a ), std::end( a ), first, 0 );
std::advance( first, increment );
```

Instead of the outer loop you could use algorithm std::generate.